# Replace Sql no meio do texto

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Banco de Dados SQL Server , Coluna é um Varchar(9) . e preciso arrumar esse dado por que preciso filtrar apenas pelas pessoas com mais de 50 anos e dessa  forma que estão nao estou conseguindo , mais caso alguem saiba um filtro que se encaixe nesse modo que esta ja me ajuda tambem.
Estou com a seguinte situação, tenho uma tabela com uma coluna `DataNascimento`, onde esta copulado com diversas datas, porém esta em um padrão errado, ex: `12-oct-69`, e eu gostaria de mudar para `12-10-69`.

Sei usar o `replace`, mas não no meio do texto, sei que se usar o `right` eu posso pegar de um pedaço do texto mais e o final vai ser modificado.

Entao gostaria de saber se tem algum comando pra mudar somente o meio dele e preservar os 3 primeiros caracteres e os demais caracteres depois do 6:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o SGDB que está usando? Qual o tipo de coluna? O que ja tentou fazer?

Comment: Copulado? Tem certeza?

Comment: @Sorack capaz mesmo, olha o ano: `12-oct-69` - fora que ta cheio de conjuge, companheiro, e tem filho também, o que sustenta a tese.

Comment: @Sorack cara é um banco com informações sobre usuarios cadastrados do sistema , eu recebo um arquivo de um orgão publico e jogo no banco , e agora eu preciso filtrar por maiores de 50 anos e dessa forma que esta não consigo

Comment: @FlavioSs nós queremos saber qual banco de dados é (`MySQL`, `SQL Server`, `Oracle`, etc?). Também é interessante que você acrescente qual o tipo de dado da sua coluna: `VARCHAR`, `DATE`, `DATETIME`? Qual deles é? Feito isso seria interessante que você desse alguma informação se você quer só buscar o dado de outra forma, porque se já estiver em `DATE` o tipo de dado já está correto.

Comment: @Sorack é SqlServer , o campo datanascimento é um varchar de (9)

Comment: @FlavioSs importante [edit] o post com o máximo de detalhes que puder, e onde exatamente está a dificuldade em resolver, pois quem sabe estando mais elaborada seja possível a comunidade reabrir. O campo de comentários é para coisas mais "voláteis" por assim dizer.

Comment: @Bacco dei uma editada na pergunta , acho que ficou mais explicado agora , obrigado

Comment: @FlavioSs e para adicionar algo mais ao que o Bacco citou, o que você quer não é nem transformar o dado, você quer filtrar. Quando tiver alguma dúvida, tente colocar sua dúvida original e não o que você pensa que resolveria. No caso do seu banco eu diria que para transformar a data teríamos um problema grande que é o de identificar em qual século a data está persente. se a data for 16-JUN-19 será 16/06/1919 ou 16/06/2019?

Comment: @Sorack ai que esta o problema eu tambem nao tenho certeza , mais eu estou partindo do pressuposto que nao tera ninguem com 100 anos , entao pra mim seria 2019

Comment: @FlavioSs coloca isso na sua pergunta

Comment: @FlavioSs, outra coisa, você colou na internet informações sensíveis, tente ofuscar ou baralhar os dados, coloque exemplo mais próximo da realidade, mas dados como CPF nome completo, são delicados.

Comment: @David entendi , eu arrumei a imagem

Comment: Sugiro você alterar a pergunta para, como alterar um varchar com data no formato '15-JUL-82'  para outro varchar no formato '15-07-82' no T-SQL no  SQL Server, pelo que entendi a dúvida é só esta, correto?

Answer (score 2):

A solução convém que também substitua o nome do mês pelo número, de forma a ser uma data válida.

Abaixo está uma das possíveis soluções (criada uma tabela de exemplo, `Datas`):

```
;WITH CTE(NumMes, Mes) AS
(
    SELECT  1
        ,   FORMAT(CAST('2000-01-01' AS DATE), 'MMM')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  NumMes + 1
        ,   FORMAT(CAST('2000-' + CAST(NumMes + 1 AS NVARCHAR(2)) + '-01' AS DATE), 'MMM')
    FROM    CTE
    WHERE   NumMes < 12
)
SELECT  *
INTO    #Meses
FROM    CTE

CREATE TABLE Datas([Data] NVARCHAR(9))

INSERT INTO Datas VALUES('01-DEC-43'), ('15-JUL-82'), ('08-MAR-07')

SELECT      REPLACE([Data], SUBSTRING([Data], 4, 3), RIGHT('00' + CAST(M.Nummes AS NVARCHAR(2)), 2))
FROM        Datas   D
INNER JOIN  #Meses  M ON M.Mes = SUBSTRING([Data], 4, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Considerando-se os estilos definidos na função CONVERT(), os dados estão no estilo 6. Se o objetivo é converter de dd-mês-aa para dd-mm-aa, então é um processo bem simples:

```
-- código #3
SELECT DNB, 
       convert (char(8), convert (date, DNB, 6), 5) as DNB2
  from tabela;
```

No código acima DNB é a coluna DataNascimentoBeneficiario.

---

Mas se é necessário acrescentar o "século", e considerando-se os estilos definidos na função CONVERT(), os dados estão no estilo 6, a princípio bastaria fazer a seguinte conversão:

```
-- código #1
SELECT DNB, 
       convert (date, DNB, 6) as DNB_2
  from tabela;
```

No código acima DNB é a coluna DataNascimentoBeneficiario.

A função CONVERT() trata os valores de ano, acrescentando ou 19 ou 20 como "século". Entretanto, a regra que ela utiliza para definição de "século" não é confiável para o caso. Por exemplo, 08-MAR-20 ela converte para 8 de março de 2020: data inválida para o caso, que é data de nascimento de uma pessoa.

Considerando-se que é data de nascimento, uma opção é definir o século considerando-se o ano corrente: se o ano na data é maior do que 19 (ano corrente), então a data é do século passado; caso contrário, é do século atual.

```
-- código #2
declare @AnoCorrente tinyint;
set @AnoCorrente= year (current_timestamp) % 100;

with tabela_2 as (
  SELECT *, 
       (left (DNB, 7) 
        + case when cast (right (DNB, 2) as tinyint) > @AnoCorrente
                                 then '19' else '20' end 
        + right (DNB, 2)) as DNB2 
  from tabela
)  
SELECT DNB, 
       convert (date, DNB, 6) as DNB_6,
       convert (date, DNB2, 106) as DNB_106
  from tabela_2;
```

No código acima a data é convertida usando os dois métodos e na análise dos resultados percebe-se que a nova regra é confiável.

Pode-se reforçar a confiabilidade da conversão utilizando também a informação da coluna que contém o grau de parentesco.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você tem que converter para um formato que o SQL SERVER entenda (veja : https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
Sugiro algo como :

```
SELECT @dataTexto  = SUBSTRING(@DataNascimentoBeneficiario, 4, 3) SUBSTRING(@DataNascimentoBeneficiario, 1, 2) + "," + SUBSTRING(@DataNascimentoBeneficiario, 8, 2)
```

(Documentação sobre Substring em https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 )

Que converteria 15-JUL-82 para JUL 15, 1982 (Data do tipo 7)

```
select @dataDateFormat = CONVERT(DATE, @dataTexto, 7)
```

Então converter para texto novamente no formato que você deseja, usando datepart https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
SELECT @novoFormatoDataEmTexto = DATEPART(dd,@dataDateFormat)+"-"+DATEPART(mm,@dataDateFormat)+"-"+DATEPART(yy,@dataDateFormat)
```

Usei variáveis pois é mais fácil e talvez até mais performático usando cursor, mas você pode substituir cada lugar que a variável aparece, pelo conteúdo dela para que fique tudo num único SELECT, embora vai ficar de difícil compreensão.

Comment: Obrigado , funcionou aqui

Comment: @FlavioSs O estilo 7 tem o mesmo problema do estilo 6, com relação a definir o século. Por exemplo, SALVADOR DE PRIMA nasceu em 25-NOV-30; se utilizar o estilo 7 direto, a data é convertida para 25 de novembro de 2030. Considerando-se que é data de nascimento, ele ainda vai nascer.

Comment: @Flávio SS pelo que entendi do texto seu texto não era sobre o século. Este problema do século é outro problema que você vai ter pela massa de dados não prever o século, você vai ter que utilizar outras informações para definir de que século se refere cada linha pois só com algo como 01-10-30 não tem como saber se é 1930 ou 2030. O problema seu pelo que entendi era de conversão de texto e isto foi resolvido, certo?